# Multiple dynamic forms in a modal but how to submit?

Tags: jquery, forms

I´m completely stuck on this one. I really don´t know what to do anymore so if anyone is willing to help me, have some examples or point me in some directions that would be very useful.

This is the situation:

I have a modal (eric martins simplemodal) window where some forms are generated with some JSON details. This is done with the code below:

```
         $.each(data.product.variants, function(index, variant){     

          contentHtml = contentHtml +
            '<div id="form">' +
            '<form class="formProduct" id="formProduct'+variant.id+'" action="#" >' +
            '<div class="variants">' +
            '<div class="pop_variantTitle"><label><input type="hidden" id="variantId" name="'+ variant.id + '" value="' + variant.id + '" />' + variant.title + '</label></div>' +
            '<div class="pop_variantQuantity"><label">{{ 'Quantity' | t }}: <input type="text" name="quantity" id="formProductQuantity" value="1" /></label></div>' +
            '<div class="pop_variantAdd"><a class="button green submit" href="#"><span>{{ 'Add to cart' | t }}</span></a></div>' + //
            '</div>' +
            '</form>' +
            '</div>';
         });     
        $('.formProductContent').html(contentHtml);
      });         
    }})
  return false;
  })

  $().ready(function(){

var form = $('form').attr('id');

$(form).submit(function() { return false; });

$(".submit").live("click", function(){

var quantity = $("#formProductQuantity").val();
var variant = $("#variantId").val();

$(".submit").replaceWith("send...");

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '{{ 'cart/add/' }}'+variant+'/?quantity='+quantity+'',
data: $(form).serialize(), //"formProduct"
success: function(data) {
/*if(data == "true") {
$(form).fadeOut("fast", function(){
$(this).before("<p><strong>Success! Your feedback has been sent, thanks :)</strong></p>");
setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
});
}*/
 }
});
});
});
```

The script itself works nicely. 
I know that to submit these forms I have to work with unique id's or unique submit buttons. I tried al sort of things but I only can achieve to submit the first form. Can anybody help me with some directions or examples or everything that can help me ;)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$(".submit").live("click", function(){
    //code
}
```

with

```
$(".submit").each(function(){
    $(this).live("click", function(){
        //code
    }
});
```

.class selector return all classes but you need to process them. For your code, it will work only with first .class found.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing is submitted now. You say that how my script is build that this is the only way... perhaps you have a better/easier way to code such modal with forms? +1 for your help